# Jmeter > File Upload > Amazon : Unable to make a file upload in our application while recording script

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have a file upload request  in my application , while I tried to upload file via bin folder of jmeter still the am unable to upload the attachment
is there a way to capture the missed out request on which the actual file upload is being passed through (edited) 
Solutions that I have tried :

1.) tried to upload the file from the bin folder of Jmeter - Did not get captured in the file uploads section of the http sample.

2.) tried manually configuring the path of the file , by going to the file upload > browse> select , and provider parameter name  but not sure of the MIME type for the zip file hence left the MIME field alone blank.

3.) tired looking for the network from the chrome developer tool and add two other request that did not get recorded manually from the request header, form data and request payload.
The tricky part is , when I record the script , the two other request that see on the network of the developer tool is not captured
additionally for file upload operation I can see a request going to the amazon

Request header data :

> Request URL: https://cw-staging-virginia.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/
>
> Request Method: POST Status  Code: 201  Created Remote Address:
>   13.33.170.36:443
>
> Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade (edited)
>
> Form data key:
>   CMCHN/Query/Attachments/query_2488998/ManageQA-siteDown.png
>
> AWSAccessKeyId: AKIAJGTSHK5HFKMKAZBA a cl: private policy:
>   eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjogIjIwMTktMDItMTlUMTM6MzU6MTkuMzI4WiIsImNvbmRpdGlvbnMiOlt7ImFjbCI6InByaXZhdGUifSx7InN1Y2Nlc3NfYWN0aW9uX3N0YXR1cyI6IjIwMSJ9LHsiYnVja2V0IjoiY3ctc3RhZ2luZy12aXJnaW5pYSJ9LFsic3RhcnRzLXdpdGgiLCIka2V5IiwiQ01DSE4vUXVlcnkvQXR0YWNobWVudHMvcXVlcnlfMjQ4ODk5OCJdXX0=
>   signature: G8MWN8gEFbcT/dAyOTvqVQnUekc= success_action_status: 201
>   file: (binary).

Any help please. Highly appreciable

Comment: Could you show your test plan and reqests settings?